# get a data from an array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

get a data from an array ..code for getting cart

```
public function show()
{
    $data = $this->cartService->getCart(auth()->user()->id);
    dd($data);
    
}
```

Response

```
 array:2 [
  "cart" => array:9 [
    "id" => 244
    "user_id" => 53
    "total_mrp" => "56000.00"
    "promo" => "HELLO"
    "discount" => "30.00"
    "meta" => {#1575
      +"sub_total": 56000
    }
  ]
  "cart_items" => array:1 [

      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

**HOW CAN I GET PROMO IN A Variabel???**
i tried

```
return $data->promo;
```

but error

Comment: as it is array you need to do `return $data['cart']['promo'];`

Comment: you have 2 arrays, you need: dd($data['cart']['promo'])

Comment: ErrorException: Undefined index: promo in file

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collect()`. You can read about this function from [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-collect)

```
$data = $this->cartService->getCart(auth()->user()->id);

$cart = collect($data['cart']??[]);
dd($cart->get('promo'));
```